# POST relative date in SOAP request via PowerAutomate

Tags: xml, post, soap, power-automate

Rather than POSTing a static date in SOAP request `<fromDate xsi:type="xsd:string">2022-01-01</fromDate>`

I am POSTing a relative date in the format below in SOAP request. It works perfectly in SOAPUI but fails in PowerAutomate flow. Any idea as to why or an alternative to my issue.

`<fromDate xsi:type="xsd:string">${=def now = new Date();now.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}</fromDate>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what and where you're doing this but the correct expression within PowerAutomate/LogicApps would be something like this ...

```
@{formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

... so to give you an example, setting the value of a variable like this ...

```
<fromDate xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">@{formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}</fromDate>
```

[image: XML]

... will produce this result.

[image: Result]

You can also see that I've converted the UTC date/time to the time zone I'm in to give me exactly what I want.